# Web and mobile site icons not loading properly in ios devices

Tags: ios, vue.js, icons

I am currently developing a web and a mobile site [sellist.com](https://www.sellist.com), [m.sellist.com](https://m.sellist.com/) using VueJs and Laravel and I have applied icons to the navbar using [iconmoon.io](https://icomoon.io/docs.html).

But some of the icons are not loading properly when I check it in ios devices. It was loading fine in other devices.

Please refer the screenshot of the icons which causes the issue.

[image]

But those should look like the below images. And those are showing as it is in all the devices other than ios devices.
[image]   [image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: its cropping for some reason or either its giving different value :/ didnt found these icons on your website

Comment: I have added the mobile site as well. Check the side navigation bar for the icons

Comment: i can see same icon that you gave here, im using chrome, MacOS. Same means the error one is showing

Comment: Yeah. It happens only in ios devices. The icons shows fine in other devices. Do you happen to know why?